# Adding addiotional email from products custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I am trying to add a new email to order confirmation. Now I am able to use the order's custom fields to ad a new extra email address. But i would like to use a custom field from the **product** instead.

Below is what I have done so far.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'additional_customer_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // New Order 
function additional_customer_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    $extra_mail = get_post_meta($prod_id,'extra_email',true);
    $recipient = $extra_mail;

    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: Which custom field is it about? (metakey) and an order generally consists of several products. What should happen in that case if several products contain the same field with a different value?

Comment: You are currently accessing order ID not items IDs so foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) { $product_id = $item->get_product_id();} now we know the product ids from there you can access your field per product

Comment: Why client order template have to be send to second email ? If you want second email to notify you for orders go to woo settings and add as much emails you want. It will use admin order template instead.

Comment: I would suggest using woocommerce_new_order hook and use wp_mail(). If you rly need to send it to another email.